# Synonymize [select2] and [jquery-select2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select2) (905) and [jquery-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-select2) (2267) cover the same topic and should be synonymized. There is already [one upvote for this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-select2/synonyms), however I don't have the "required score" necessary to upvote or approve it myself, so if those who do, or a mod could do so, it would be appreciated.